# how to find longest and shortest string in c program?

Tags: c, max, min, c-strings, strlen

I try to make a program to find the shortest and longest string using function and array but the program doesn't work. the program does not display the function ordered.
here my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void Max(char x[][1000], int n);
void Min(char x[][1000],int n);

void Max(char x[][1000], int n){
    int i,Max,len1,c;
    Max=strlen(x[0]);
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        len1=strlen(x[i]);
        if(len1>Max)
        {
            c=i;
            Max=len1;
        }
    }printf("\nthe longest string among all is \"%s\" \n \n",x[c]);
}
void Min(char x[][1000],int n){
    int i,min,len2,d;
    min=strlen(x[0]);
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
        len2=strlen(x[i]);
        if(len2<min)
        {
            d=i;
            min=len2;
        }
    }
    printf("\n the shortest string among all is \"%s\" \n \n",x[d]);
}
int main(){
    
    int i,jmlh=0,n,z;
    printf("How many name to accept: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char x[n][1000];
    printf("\nEnter %d words: \n");
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
        gets(x[i]);
    }
    Max(x,n);
    Min(x,n);
    
    return 0;
}
```

the input is

```
3
```

and input :

```
robin van persie
lionel messi
ronaldo
```

and should an output like this :

```
the longest string among all is "robin van persie".
the shortest string among all is "ronaldo".
```

maybe anybody wants to help me to fixed this program and I really need your opinion. thank you

Comment: you don't initialize c or d. Please read your compiler warnings and fix them

Comment: Note that [The `gets()` function is so dangerous that it should never be used!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used)  It is no longer a part of Standard C.  Any teacher teaching you to use it needs to go back to relearn remedial (modern) C.  Granted, using `char x[n][1000];` gives an array big enough that you're unlikely to run into overflows, but even that size of array doesn't remove the possibility.

Comment: The functions `Max()` and `Min()` should be more similar (there's no need for `len1` vs `len2`, nor `c` versus `d`; differential capitalization of `Max` vs `min` in the functions), and neither function should print anything.  Rather, the functions should return the index of the longest or shortest string and the calling code (`main()`) should handle the printing.  Separating I/O (printing) from 'calculations' is a basic technique of good programming.  It makes the calculation more nearly reusable in other programs — not yet a primary concern of yours, but it will become one over time.

Comment: It's also not a particularly good idea to use the name of the function as the name of a variable within the function — even if the intent is to ensure that recursion is impossible.  You have a local variable `Max` within function `Max()` — your skin should be crawling as if there are bugs trying to creep over it.

Comment: whether in my min function is correct it will produce the shortest string?. im not sure about my program

Comment: Your `Min()` function will not reliably produce the correct answer if the first entry in the array (index 0) is the shortest string.  Similarly, your `Max()` function will not reliably produce the correct answer if the first entry in the array (index 0) is the longest string.

Comment: what if the shortest word was on another line? what should i do to change it ? @JonathanLeffler

Comment: Which part of the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65181402/15168) by [Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2877241/vlad-from-moscow) do you not understand?

Comment: i understand it but in my min function there is an error like  it's only show the first line who same to the longest  sentence

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225624/discussion-between-pratama-and-jonathan-leffler).

Answer (score 0):

Neither the variable c nor the variable d was initialized in the functions `Max` and `Min`.

```
int i,Max,len1,c;
```

and

```
int i,min,len2,d;
```

At least change these declarations like

```
int i,Max,len1,c = 0;
```

and

```
int i,min,len2,d = 0;
```

You are entering n + 1 elements in this loop

```
for(i=0;i<=n;i++){
```

but passing to the functions only the value `n` instead of `n + 1`.

Pay attention to the fact that the function [`gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) is so unsafe that it is not supported by the C Standard any more. Instead, use the function `fgets`.

Comment: whether in my min function is correct it will produce the shortest string?

Comment: @pratama If you will update the function it should produce a correct result.

Comment: where should I add this int i,min,len2,d;? . like this : void Min(char x[][1000],int n,int int i,int min,int len2,int d;); ?

Comment: @pratama You need to initialize the variables c and  d with 0. What is unclear?

Comment: @pratama What have you added> Show in a comment your addition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225621/discussion-between-pratama-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: i add like this :int i,Max,len1,c=0;
inside the function

Comment: @pratama And in the loop in main change the condition to i < n instead of i <= n

Comment: yes, but the program only show the longest words

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void Max(char x[][1000], int n);
void Min(char x[][1000],int n);

void Max(char x[][1000], int n){
 int i,Max,len1,c=0; // c=0 (in case x[0] is the max) otherwise x[c] is undefined
 Max=strlen(x[0]);
 for(i=1;i<n;i++){ // i<n because I starts from 0
    len1=strlen(x[i]);
    if(len1>Max)
    {
        c=i;
        Max=len1;
    }
 }printf("\nthe longest string among all is \"%s\" \n \n",x[c]);
}
void Min(char x[][1000],int n){
 int i,min,len2,d=0; // d=0 otherwise if min=x[0], x[d]is undefined
 min=strlen(x[0]);
 for(i=1;i<n;i++){
    len2=strlen(x[i]);
    if(len2<min)
    {
        d=i;
        min=len2;
    }
}
printf("\n the shortest string among all is \"%s\" \n \n",x[d]);
}
int main(){

 int i,n,c;
 printf("How many name to accept: ");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 char x[n][1000];
 printf("\nEnter %d words: \n",n);
 while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
 for(i=0;i<n;i++){ // i<n because i starts from 0 (and not from 1)
    fgets(x[i],sizeof x[i],stdin); // fgets is more secure than gets
    

 }

 Max(x,n);
 Min(x,n);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: And are you going to explain what you changed and why you changed it?  I know that the variables `jmlh` and `z` are in the question, but what benefit or service do they provide, other than being a source of warnings about unused variables when the code is compiled with sensible options?  Remember, too, that `fgets()` includes the newline in the buffer.  You probably need to remove it: `x[i][strcspn(x[i], "\n")] = '\0';` is a good way to do that.

Comment: while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { } can you explain this

Comment: i don't understand in line: while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
 for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    fgets(x[i],sizeof x[i],stdin);

Comment: while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { } . This instruction allows to remove newlines in the buffer. Otherwise, when you input a name, the next input will be newline and not the next name , do you understand me ?

Comment: can you write it in simple c code statement cause i don't understand @nissimabehcera

Comment: @pratama while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }  => while newline or end of the stream aren't reached, the program continue to remove character in the buffer